# Making the Windows Terminal Usable

Tags: windows, terminal, powershell, development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [maximizing the windows Command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/170745/maximizing-the-windows-command-prompt)

What I'd like is a way to make the command prompt and PowerShell a little more user friendly. Some basics of a good terminal or terminal emulator would be great. For example, being able to maximize both to fit the whole screen or even full screen would help quite a bit.  In UNIX based environments, terminal, xterm, konsole, etc maximize to fit the screen and can also full screen.  This functionality was also a part of Windows OS's back in the old days, but since Windows Vista that functionality has been removed.  Is there any way to add it back?

Comment: See [Maximizing the Windows Command prompt](http://superuser.com/questions/170745/maximizing-the-windows-command-prompt) and also [Full Screen Command Prompt in Vista](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/274205-full-screen-command-prompt-in-vista) (works in Win7 as well).

Comment: "make ... usable" isn't really a question, and "usable" is highly subjective. We have been *using* the Windows console for decades!

Please focus specifically on what you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

[Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) might help. So could [PowerCMD](http://www.powercmd.com/). If you [Google Command Prompt Alternative](https://www.google.com/search?q=command%20prompt%20alternative) you should be able to find something that suits your needs.

As for PowerShell, I really like the PowerShell ISE.

If you can't install an alternative on a server, see if you can have telnet enabled and use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), or better yet SSH. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows) might help get SSH going.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) as terminal emulator with [clink](https://code.google.com/p/clink/) to have some of the joys of Bash. ConEmu have some very useful features like macros and custom key binding and clink bring things like history search and Bash shortcuts

Comment: I'll be checking this out.  Thank you very much.