# How to open `cmd.exe` maximized from the explorer context menu?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to set up the new Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to open from the context menu:

[image]

So far I followed the tutorial on http://winaero.com/blog/add-bash-to-the-folder-context-menu-in-windows-10/, and was able to add it as on the image above. The process is basically set the following Windows Registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\openbashhere]
@="Open Bash Here"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,4c,00,\
  6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,6c,00,78,00,73,00,73,00,5c,00,62,00,61,00,73,\
  00,68,00,2e,00,69,00,63,00,6f,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\openbashhere\command]
@="cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\" && bash.exe"
```

Here the problem is the line `"cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\" && bash.exe"`, I could not figure out a command to correctly open it maximized. I searched and found some threads about it:

1. [maximizing the windows Command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/170745/maximizing-the-windows-command-prompt)
2. [Why doesn't the Windows command prompt window maximize to the full screen size?](https://superuser.com/questions/80094/why-doesnt-the-windows-command-prompt-window-maximize-to-the-full-screen-size)
3. [Adding Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 to Explorer Context Menu (Issues)](https://superuser.com/questions/1110050/adding-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10-to-explorer-context-menu-issues)
4. [How can I launch cmd.exe minimized?](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=926299)

I tried to do this tricky play:

```
cmd.exe /c start /max cmd.exe
```

It works if I type it on the Run dialog:

[image]

But if I try to put it on the above registry entry, it does not open it maximized:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\openbashhere\command]
@="cmd.exe /c start /max cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\" && bash.exe"
```

Later I also tried another dirty trick with a shortcut to `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\cmd.exe.lnk"`, which opens the cmd maximixed, but when I put it in place of the `cmd.exe`:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\openbashhere\command]
@="\"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\cmd.exe.lnk\" /c cd /d \"%V\" && bash.exe"
```

Windows throws this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about the [`&&` command separator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

> `commandA && commandB`             Run `commandA`, if it succeeds then run
>   `commandB`

In your `@="cmd.exe /c start /max cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\" && bash.exe"`:

- `commandA` = `start /max cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\"`
- `commandB` = `bash.exe`

Hence, `bash.exe` is launched from the first/outer `cmd /c` instance (unmaximized, generally).

Moreover, read about [*title* in `start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

**Use either** ([escape ampersands](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html))

```
@="cmd.exe /c start \"\" /max cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\" ^&^& bash.exe"
```

**or, maybe better** (omit inner `cmd /c` at all)

```
@="cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\" && start \"\" /max bash.exe"
```