# Registry command to open program minimized

Tags: windows

I have added a .bat file to the context menu of .avi files with the following .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\avi_auto_file\shell\RemuxvideotoMKV]
@="Remux video to MKV"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\avi_auto_file\shell\RemuxvideotoMKV\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MKVToolNix\\Remux video to MKV.bat\" \"%1\""
```

It works. I now want the .bat file to start minimized.

I found an answer for almost exactly the same problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1230490/how-to-open-cmd-exe-maximized-from-the-explorer-context-menu), but I don't understand the syntax, as it refers to a slightly more complex command.

Comment: I think you want to precede your MKV.bat with a call to `start`, https://ss64.com/nt/start.html, specifying /MIN and taking the advice to include a title.

Comment: Thanks. This is as close as I got to building something out of that: `@="start "Remux video to MKV" "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\" /min "Remux video to MKV.bat"`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Read [Commands that are Internal to the CMD shell](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html). You need to run `cmd /C start …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) the following should work:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\avi_auto_file\shell\RemuxvideotoMKV\command]
@="cmd /C start \"remux\" /MIN \"C:\\Program Files\\MKVToolNix\\Remux video to MKV.bat\" \"%1\""
```

`start` starts a batch or program, the `/MIN` switch starts the program minimised. There's also a `/B` to run without creating a new window.

As @JosefZ pointed out because `start` is [part of the cmd shell](https://ss64.com/nt/index.html) (dotted entries in that link) it needs to be run from `cmd`.

Comment: Thanks. How would this work without calling for "vanilla CMD"? I actually have ConEmu set to handle all .bat files with this .reg file: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\ConEmu\\ConEmu64.exe\" /cmd \"%1\" %*"` and using the command you provided indeed works, but CMD pops up for a second and then minimizes into the taskbar, while opening minimized with ConEmu would have no popup and minimizes to the system tray, making the entire process completely silent.

Comment: I'm going to mark it as solved on the basis that it does solve what I asked. ConEmu is, I suppose, a further problem that applies to very few people. Thank you again.