# Can I customize the color scheme in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, colors

For example, I'd like blue to be a little bit lighter, or change red to be a bit more orangeish. Is this possible?

I know that I can change the background and foreground colors easily. What about the other colors?

Comment: What other colours? Background is... the background, foreground is the text. There isn't really anything else to change in a CLI.

Comment: For example, the color of the error message when you type `somecommandthatdoesntexist`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you know, one can easily change the PowerShell console colours using something like this in your profile:

```
$a = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$a.ForegroundColor = "black"
$a.BackgroundColor = "white"
Clear-Host
```

However, you are limited to the standard 16 ANSI colours.  You may be able to alter the colours used as the defaults in the registry (I can vaguely remember doing so in the past, but I cannot find any notes on it), but an easy way to do it would be to wrap the PowerShell console with [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and use the options in its settings.  You'd also get other benefits, like tabs and easy pasting.

---

EDIT:  I just remembered that you can do the same without using Console2.  In the standard PowerShell console, just go to the Colour tab in Properties and modify the RGB values of the standard 16 ANSI colours.

Comment: That's great information. I'm thinking of scripting this---do you know of a way to detect which Registry values are changing?

Comment: @AndresRiofrio: Yes, just use `RegShot` before and after making the changes and see what the difference is, to find the relevant registry key.  You can then inject the same value using `reg add`.